# What about stealing "shares" from links in edited questions

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, share-this

How should I react, if I'm editing a text (question or answer), which contains links to other Stack Exchange's site content, but user is  using full-blown URLs (i.e. those taken from browser's bar), not the ones available under `Share` link.

`Share` link's URLs always contains my own ID to track how many stuff *I have shared*. But I'm neither OP not the one, who actually answered the question. I'm just editing stuff / fixing something.

Can I change such link to the one taken from `Share` link? Or will I be seen as share-whore just like many of you sees rep-whores (and want to burn them down)?

Or, should I leave such links as they are?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please don't change them to share links. In fact, you should prefer using the full-blown links whenever possible. A lot of people will look at the hyperlink when hovering over it to see the slug and get an idea of what question they'd be visiting, which is especially useful when the link text is not the title of the question.

But past that, share links that come from within the Stack Exchange network itself do not contribute to your totals for the sharing badges. It really doesn't matter whose ID number is on the end of it, and you can actually just completely remove the user ID on it - the link will still work properly.

Answer (score 7):

If someone is leaving bare URLs in questions or answers, they should be replaced with a link (descriptive text + URL). I don't really see a reason to replace the URL with a shortened Share URL. Shares within the Stack Exchange network don't count towards badges, so there's nothing lost or gained from it.

Comment: Can elaborate your last sentence? "_Shares within the Stack Exchange network don't count towards badges_". And when they count? I asked here, because this is central question about problem, that I faced on many SE sites. But I'm not talking about shares through any metas only on "main" sites of SE.

Comment: Ah, I see. Share links only counts toward badges, if they're visited from external URLs, from outside SE? Am I right?

Comment: @trejder Yes, that's right. Shares are tracked if they come from reddit, Twitter, Facebook, your blog, etc. Shares from within the SE network don't count towards anything.